# Response code 500 in JMeter when running with threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Getting the following error in JMeter while running the list of APIs (with no of threads:1-140 with ramp up period-1).

```
Response code:500
Response message: Internal Server Error
```

How should I overcome this Error Response code in order to get the accurate response?
What should do to decrease amount of response with this response code?

Comment: We also getting same error when running JMeter for saving and loading the form in application.While the same error is not coming when manually operated.                                                                                              There is no problem from Application Server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general a 500 is an unhandled response on the part of a developer.  Usually on the backend but also on the performance testing tool front end.

Ask yourself, are you validating responses that come back from the server for appropriate content?  I am not just suggesting an HTTP200 is valid.  You need to check response content to ensure that it is what you expect is valid for the business process, for you can have a completely valid HTTP200 class page which contains a response which will send your business process off the rails.  If you do not handle the exception on the part of the unexpected response then you will find that one to two steps down the road in the business process then you are pretty much guaranteed that you will find a 500 as your request is completely out of context with the state of the application at that point.

Test101, for every step there is an expected and positive result which allows the business process to continue.  Check for that result and branch your code when you do not find that the result is true.

Or, if this is a single step business process then you are likely handing the service poor data and the developer has not fully fleshed out the graceful part of dealing with your poor data.

Answer (score 0):

The general advice in [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) is Ramp-up = number of threads, in your case 140

> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

Currently you are sending every 1/140 seconds new thread which is almost simultaneously, the reason to the change is:

> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test

Answer (score 0):

Status code - 500 comes from server/API's and it's not an issue of Jmeter. Sometimes the concurrent requests are rejected by server as it's too weak to handle that number of requests.In my case, I asked my server team to scale up servers so that we can test the underlying API . It's worth mentioning that sometimes Jmeter also runs out of memory. You can do some tweaking in `set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m` property of jmeter execuble file. Also listeners consume too much resources.Try not to use them.